# Syntax guide & versioning for Caffe prototxt

Tags: caffe

Is there a succinct syntax guide to the Caffe `prototxt` file format anywhere? Clearly there are older and newer versions - is there any versioning system associated with it?

I notice that in some versions, you see things like (with my `# comments`):

```
input_dim: 80    # specifies batch size?
input_dim: 3     # specifies image data channels
input_dim: 224   # specifies image width
input_dim: 224   # specifies image height
```

while in others (in fact in a `deploy.prototxt` file) you see:

```
input_param { shape: { dim: 10 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } }
```

and elsewhere you see explicit `batch_size` parameters. But wait a moment: in what sense would the `10` parameter make sense as a batch size when deploying the network? Why would there be batches at all?

It seems unnecessarily confusing to me -- is there any single document which specifies the syntax, clarifies what syntax is new/old/deprecated/unsupported, specifies what roles the files play (network architectural spec, network training parameters, other?) and untangles the confusion?

Comment: yes. read the comments in `caffe.proto` file.

Comment: I found the comments so unhelpful, I switched to tensorflow.

Comment: have you looked at [caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers.html)?